How can I create a new random shape for a Tetris-like game?
I want to have new tetris pieces to appear in the game the longer you play and it doesn't work, it makes new shapes but the shapes aren't centered, they aren't continuous (like the shape might look like 2 shapes because they aren't touching), and it sometimes adds a shape that's already part of the shapes array. Each shape has a max squares of 12 and must fit in a 4x4 space
Here's my code so far:
function randomShape(score) {
  const maxSize = 12; // Max number of squares per shape
  const centerOffset = 1; // Offset to center the shape
  const maxComplexity = Math.min(Math.floor(score / 100), 6); // Max complexity based on score

  let shape;

  do {
    shape = Array.from({ length: 4 }, () => Array(4).fill(0)); // Create an empty 4x4 shape
    const size = Math.max(1, Math.floor(Math.random() * (maxComplexity + 1))); // Shape size varies based on complexity

    let squaresToPlace = Math.min(size, maxSize); // Limit the squares placed to maxSize

    // Fill the shape with random positions of 1s based on size
    while (squaresToPlace > 0) {
      const x = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4);
      const y = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4);

      // Only place a 1 if the spot is empty
      if (shape[y][x] === 0) {
        shape[y][x] = 1;
        squaresToPlace--;
      }
    }
  } while (!shape.flat(5).includes(1)); // Retry if the shape is empty

  // Centering logic
  const centeredShape = Array.from({ length: 4 }, () => Array(4).fill(0));

  // Get the positions of all filled cells
  const filledPositions = [];
  for (let r = 0; r < 4; r++) {
    for (let c = 0; c < 4; c++) {
      if (shape[r][c] === 1) {
        filledPositions.push({ r, c });
      }
    }
  }

  let amount = 0;
  shape.flat(5).forEach((s) => {
    if (s === 1) amount++;
  });
  if (amount === 1) {
    return [
      [0, 0, 0, 0],
      [0, 0, 0, 0],
      [0, 0, 1, 0],
      [0, 0, 0, 0],
    ];
  }

  // Determine how to center the shape
  const minRow = Math.min(...filledPositions.map((p) => p.r));
  const maxRow = Math.max(...filledPositions.map((p) => p.r));
  const minCol = Math.min(...filledPositions.map((p) => p.c));
  const maxCol = Math.max(...filledPositions.map((p) => p.c));

  // Calculate the offsets needed to center the shape
  const height = maxRow - minRow + 1;
  const width = maxCol - minCol + 1;

  // Calculate vertical and horizontal offsets
  const rowOffset = Math.floor((4 - height) / 2); // Center vertically
  const colOffset = Math.floor((4 - width) / 2); // Center horizontally

  // Place the shape in the centered position
  filledPositions.forEach(({ r, c }) => {
    // Ensure we're placing the piece within bounds
    const newRow = r + rowOffset;
    const newCol = c + colOffset;
    if (newRow >= 0 && newRow < 4 && newCol >= 0 && newCol < 4) {
      centeredShape[newRow][newCol] = 1;
    }
  });

  return centeredShape;
}

I tried to add new random shapes that were supposed to look normal and be centered, but they were broken and uncentered and sometimes dupes.

I assume you want random shapes but have a specific list of potential shapes like Tetris has, correct? If so, why not create an array of 2d arrays for your piece pattern. Then you can grab a random piece from the array.

I'm lost from near the start - although you've set a maximum number of pieces at 12 I can;t see how that ever gets beyond 6 - what I am I missing?

It seems your problem is not really a coding one - the JS moreorless works as far as it goes. What you need is an algorithm that works - have you tried algoritm-related sites?

As the number of possible shapes is limited, as the game progresses you will get clashes - or not be able to serve a shape. What do you want to do about that?

Well I want the shapes to be unique and random, so I don't want an array of potential shapes. Also, I want the shapes to get bigger the higher the score is, I'm not sure how I could do that with a preset array. When I run out of shapes to use, I'll stop adding more and just speed the game up after that. If it never goes past 6, then that's also something I need help with . What do you mean by algorithm related sites?

'algorithm related sites' = sites that discuss algorithms [rather than just try to debug code].

You never get beyond size 6 because you've set 6 as the maximum, see the two calculations you do to set size.

While  you could randomly select from existing arrays of shapes (different arrays for different stages in the game) if you want the full set of shapes to be possible be aware of the massive numbers involved once you get past a size of a few [so perhaps creating them on the fly is the way to do it].

You should also treat "centering" as a separate problem. First create a random shape like in a "snake" game. Keep adding one square on one side of an existing shape. After N steps the shape is finished. Then you center the shape.

I would generate all possible shapes of all sizes you need (1 to 12) in a preprocessing phase. This has the advantage that:

You only do this effort once, and
It becomes easy to ensure that all distinct shapes of a given size have equal probability of being selected. This is hard to achieve when generating a random shape from scratch.

It turns out it doesn't take much time (run snippet below to see how much). There are 2245 distinct shapes of sizes 1 to 12 on a 4x4 grid (ignoring rotations and shifts of the same shape). This is not a huge number. Storing them in an array up-front will not consume a disturbing amount of memory.
Below is code to populate twelve arrays with shapes: one per size. The snippet then reports how much time that took (less than 50ms on my laptop), and goes on to print the number of shapes it has collected per size. Finally it prints the 17 shapes that were found with size 5:


function getShapesOfSize(size) {
    if (!size) return [];

    const shapes = new Set;
    const visited = new Set;

    // Local functions:
    function align(shape) {
        while (!(shape & 0xF)) shape >>= 4;
        while (!(shape & 0x1111)) shape >>= 1;
        return shape;
    }

    const lineToArray = (shape) =>
        [shape & 1, (shape >> 1) & 1, (shape >> 2) & 1, (shape >> 3) & 1];

    function bitCount(n) {
        let count = 0;
        while (n) {
            n &= n - 1;
            count++;
        }
        return count;
    }

    function toCenterGrid(shape) {
        shape = align(shape);
        if (!(shape & 0xF000) && bitCount(shape & 0xF) > bitCount(shape & 0x0F00)) {
            shape <<= 4
        }
        if (!(shape & 0x8888) && bitCount(shape & 0x1111) > bitCount(shape & 0x4444)) {
            shape <<= 1;
        }
        return [
            lineToArray(shape),
            lineToArray(shape >> 4),
            lineToArray(shape >> 8),
            lineToArray(shape >> 12)
        ]
    }

    function rotateLine(shape) {
        shape &= 0xF;
        return ((shape << 3) | (shape << 6) | (shape << 9) | (shape << 12)) & 0x8888;
    }

    const rotate = (shape) => align(
             rotateLine(shape     )
          | (rotateLine(shape >> 4) >> 1)
          | (rotateLine(shape >> 8) >> 2)
          | (rotateLine(shape >>12) >> 3)
    );
    
    function recur(shape, curSize) {
        if (visited.has(shape)) return;
        visited.add(shape);
        if (curSize === size) {
            // Get the "minimum" of (equivalent) rotations:
            const rot90  = rotate(shape);
            const rot180 = rotate(rot90);
            shapes.add(Math.min(align(shape), rot90, rot180, rotate(rot180)));
            return;
        }
        
        // Candidates must border on the shape
        let candidates = 
              ((shape & 0x7777) << 1)
            | ((shape & 0xEEEE) >> 1)
            | ((shape & 0x0FFF) << 4)
            | ((shape & 0xFFF0) >> 4);
        while (candidates) {
            const bit = candidates & -candidates; // select
            candidates ^= bit; // clear bit
            recur(shape | bit, curSize + 1);
        }
    }
    
    recur(1, 1); // Start with corner pixel
    recur(2, 1); // Start with neighbor of corner pixel
    return Array.from(shapes, toCenterGrid);
}

// Helper to visualise a tetris shape
const shapeStr = (shape) => shape.map(line => line.join("")).join("\n")
                            .replaceAll("0", ". ").replaceAll("1", "# ");

// Preprocessing: get all possible shapes, for all sizes between 1 and 12:
const start = performance.now(); // Let's time it
const shapesPerSize = Array.from({length: 13}, (_, i) => getShapesOfSize(i));
const timeCost = performance.now() - start;

// Use this function to pick a random shape of a given size
function randomShape(size) {
    const shapes = shapesPerSize[size];
    return shapes[Math.floor(Math.random() * shapes.length)];
}

// Demo
console.log(`Preprocessing took ${Math.round(timeCost)}ms`);
let total = 0;
console.log("Number of shapes found per size:");
shapesPerSize.forEach((arr, i) => {
    console.log(`shape size ${i}: ${arr.length} shapes found`);
    total += arr.length;
});
console.log(`In total ${total} shapes were collected.`);

const size = 5;
const shapes = shapesPerSize[size];
console.log(`Here are all ${shapes.length} shapes of size ${size}:`);
for (const shape of shapes) {
    console.log(shapeStr(shape) + "\n-------");
}



